# stix2 changes spacing in mathrm

Tags: kerning, math-fonts, stix

Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
$$\mathrm{Var}$$
\end{document}
```

to the same example without the `\usepackage{stix2}`.

With stix2:
[image]

Without stix2:
[image]

With stix2, the space between the "V" and "a" letters appears too large to my eyes, whereas without it, everything looks fine.

What might be the cause of this? Is it intended behavior? Can I fix it somewhow? (Specifically, I would like to make `\operatorname{Var}` look nice, which it currently doesn't with stix2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a precise choice of `stix2`, which does

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
```

so using a font that adds no kerning between letters. I'm not sure this is a good choice.<sup>1</sup>.

The `stix2` package does

```latex
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{stix2}
```

which means it uses its own font for text (unless you pass it the `notext` option). This is a clone of Times. However, differently from many other fonts, it has a specific upright font for `\mathrm` where kerning between letters is *not* used. It's for upright variables and is not good for “multiletter identifiers” in upright type.

The code I propose below fixes this, making advantage from the fact that (textual) operators use `\operator@font` that can be changed without prejudice to `\mathrm` as intended by the package.

So I define a new symbol font called `textoperators` that uses the text font family (that is, `\familydefault`) in the OT1 encoding, as it is customary to do and redefine `\operator@font` to point to this symbol font.

One has to use `\operatorname`, though, for textual operators such as “Var”, not `\mathrm` (that's wrong anyway in this case).

For a one shot call, `\operatorname{Var}` is handy. If you have several calls to it it's better to add

```latex
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
```

in the document preamble and use `\Var` in the document body.

The code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\DeclareSymbolFont{textoperators}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{textoperators}{bold}{OT1}{\familydefault}{b}{n}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symtextoperators}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Var

$\operatorname{Var}$

\end{document}
```

Use the proper markup.

[image]

---

**Footnote.**

<sup>1</sup> Big understatement for “I think it is utterly wrong” for textual operators.

Comment: Great, thanks! As far as I understand, the main change you propose is using `{OT1}{\familydefault}` instead of `{LS1}{stix2}`, right? Could you elaborate briefly on the meaning of this change? Why does it result in kerning being used, as opposed to before? Is it still using the stix font?

Comment: Sorry if these are stupid questions...

Comment: @jhin Not stupid at all. I added some more details.